# Why is distributed source control considered harder?

Tags: version-control

It seems rather common (around here, at least) for people to recommend SVN to newcomers to source control because it's "easier" than one of the distributed options. As a very casual user of SVN before switching to Git for many of my projects, I found this to be not the case at all.

It is conceptually *easier* to set up a DCVS repository with `git init` (or whichever), without the problem of having to set up an external repository in the case of SVN.

And the base functionality between SVN, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar all use essentially identical commands to commit, view diffs, and so on. Which is all a newcomer is really going to be doing.

The small difference in the way Git requires changes to be explicitly added before they're committed, as opposed to SVN's "commit everything" policy, is conceptually simple and, unless I'm mistaken, not even an issue when using Mercurial or Bazaar.

So why is SVN considered easier? I would argue that this is simply not true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A distributed versioning system is A Very Good Thing (tm), but I find the primary barrier to adoption being educating users on the new possibilities a new SCM gives.

This coupled with an often lack-luster amount of UI tools (half-finished tortoise implementations etc), brings a blank stare to the eye of many co-workers who long since foreswore the commandline for the sake of a good UI tool.

Also, with tools like CVS I find that people loathe branching and merging because they really really don't want to be stuck an entire day doing three way merges, often not really sure which would be the right merge to do.

My point is: Start out by telling people what they gain (not just "hey watch this new cool toy"), and prep them to the fact that using a commandline IS the way to go and that frequent constant time branching is a good thing.

Many systems such as mercurial comes with complete patch-queue system, meaning that from a Continuous Integration standpoint you *know* that whatever goes into production has been approved by QA. Stuff like this is hard to do properly with CVS or SVN.

With Mercurial people would have private repositories for their current work and all developers share a developer-tree on a server. The CI system monitors the developer-tree and pulls all changes, builds, and performs unittests. If everything passes it propagates the changes to a Testing-tree from where a deliverable is built for the QA persons. Every changeset that is added gets a token. When QA deems a feature to be complete, they annotate the Testing tree with this token, and the associated changesets are then automatically propagated to the Production-tree.

Using this approach you will never commit anything by hand to the production branch, or the testing branch. Rather the state of the code, and the sign off from QA determines the contents of your production branch,

Answer (score 8):

If you use the version control only for yourself, SVN is probably harder, since the setup is harder. If you however want to work with multiple developers over the web, a server side control has advantages:

- You have one central place, that always has the official state-of-the-art source, being the SVN server
- Since everyone always merges his changes against a central server, there are much less collisions and much less manual fixing of collisions
- You have central control over the source
- You have an official revision number instead of a revision hash, being the same among all developers and showing the official progress (it's an up counting number, unlike a hash, which is just an identity fingerprint, so you can see which code is newer or older, just by this number

Comment: I don't want to sound contrary, but none of those contribute - in my mind - to any additional confusion for the use of a DVCS, since you always know the relative age between your stuff and "theirs".

Comment: I guess the revision number is a good point depending on how that number is being used; AIUI, Bazaar has a nice integer-based versioning system unlike Git and Mercurial.

Comment: Mercurial has integers, but they're repository unique, and are relative to the order at which revisions appeared in *that* repository.

Comment: If you have a large number of merge collisions you have project related coordination issues, not source control issues.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is conceptually simpler to think of a centralized repository where each developer commits his work vs. multiple copies of the entire repository, none of which represents the 'truth'.  Since most developers are familiar with the notion of a client-server model and backend database, this is a natural concept.

Of course, the very strength of distributed source control systems is that they don't have to adhere to this model, but for a newcomer, it seems easier to grasp.

Answer (score 4):

Svn forces a single work-line. You can either commit, or you can't. Having similar experiences, I don't find Hg or Git hard to use, however, I work on a team whom seem to find it nightmarish to use them.

The whole concept of auto-branching, multiple heads, when to and when not to merge completely eludes them, not to mention they have trouble breaking free of the "commit/checkout with $somecore" mentality which leads to complete confusion when they see pushes between 2 checked out copies.

( Had a problem for a while where somebody repeatedly merged 2 branches that were not supposed to be merged because they were unable to grasp the concept. )

However, the same people whom have trouble with distributed SCMS caused me to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132520/good-excuses-not-to-use-version-control)

**edit/note**  Mercurials biggest difference I've noted vs git that makes mercurial harder to use for newbies is mercurials default behavior  for push/pull is like doing git push --all  / git pull --all , which can propagate private branches and add lots of confusion ( especially as when a new branch turns up, mercurial freezes in fear and asks you how to handle it instead of just keeping on trucking ), as well as the default merge/conflict resolution tool on mac just clobbering one set of changes blindly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the toolset for SVN is much broader, so you could sit down and teach people (TortoiseSVN, RapidSVN etc) even if they did not have much conceptual idea of how the repository worked.  It is also relatively easy to get SVN hosted for you (with trac for example) without needing to know anything.  Distributed ones have not had this backing yet and I am sure opinions of them will change when they do.

Comment: TortoiseHg? Github? Fair enough, though, in terms of a broad ecosystem, SVN definitely has an edge.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that setting up a repository with a DVCS is *practically* easier, but *conceptually* harder. After all, with a centralized VCS the users do not set up their own repository, they just create an account on Assembla or have the repo set up for them.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, sorry. "Setting up a repository" *conceptually* just means "let's start keeping track of revisions", which is easy no matter what.

Comment: Will, have you ever gotten the question, "So, but where is THE repository?"

Answer (score 1):

DVCS is currently lacking good desktop clients. Despite what most people say, version control systems can be quite hard to use correctly so a good desktop client can really help - and here TortoiseSVN excels.

Answer (score 0):

We struggle to make it as easy as possible at Codice, but it's always a little bit harder to explain, of course, it depends on the audience.

For OSS projects and small teams, specially people working on their laptops and moving here and there, working at home, plane sometimes, and so on, it's pretty easy. But, whenever you talk to corporations/enterprises, they get excited about its multi-site role, but not that much about distributed at first glance. It all depends on whether the group has a majority of advanced developers or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's [poor marketing](http://jamesmckay.net/2010/03/command-line-instructions-are-not-a-good-marketing-strategy/), simple as that. Far too many DVCS introductions focus on the command line and say "wow, isn't it fantastic, you can do a merge just by typing hg merge" completely oblivious to the fact that many people (especially in Windows land) are terrified of the command line. Yes, Joel Spolsky, I'm looking at your own [hginit.com](http://hginit.com/) here -- we need a TortoiseHg version please!

Maybe it was the case two years ago that they had poor GUI implementations, but they've come on in leaps and bounds recently. TortoiseHg is now in version 1.0, and while it may not be anything to write home about visually, it's pretty solid, stable, and easy to use. TortoiseGit is also rock solid, and it does a great job of abstracting away all the complexities of the git command line.